# Why does the augmented matrix method for finding an inverse give different results for different orders of elementary row operations?

Tags: linear-algebra

Why does the augmented matrix method for finding an inverse give different results for different orders of elementary row operations?

Consider the example of elements from the Heisenberg group:
$\begin{bmatrix}1 & a & b\\ 0 & 1 & c\\ 0 & 0 &1 \end{bmatrix}$.

Now, after augmenting this matrix,

$
  \left[\begin{array}{rrr|rrr}
    1 & a & b & 1 & 0 & 0\\
    0 & 1 & c & 0 & 1 & 0\\ 
    0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1
  \end{array}\right]
$

if you subtract c times the third row from the second,

$
  \left[\begin{array}{rrr|rrr}
    1 & a & b & 1 & 0 & 0\\
    0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & -c\\ 
    0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1
  \end{array}\right]
$

then b times the third row from the first,

$
  \left[\begin{array}{rrr|rrr}
    1 & a & 0 & 1 & 0 & -b\\
    0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & -c\\ 
    0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1
  \end{array}\right]
$

and then a times the new second row from the first,

$
  \left[\begin{array}{rrr|rrr}
    1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & -a & -b\\
    0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & -c\\ 
    0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1
  \end{array}\right]
$

you then get the following matrix for the inverse:

$$\begin{bmatrix}1 & -a & -b\\ 0 & 1 & -c\\ 0 & 0 &1 \end{bmatrix}.$$

But, this is not the inverse.

I thought order of elementary row operations doesn't matter.

Comment: Did you mean "a times the new second row from the *first*"? If not, then you have not eliminated the $a$ in the original matrix, so you're not done.

Comment: @Ian Yes, I did mean first.  I'm correcting it now.  Thanks!

Comment: Once you do that and also use the *new* second row, the problem goes away entirely.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean.  Are you saying that the resulting matrix that I listed is the inverse of the former?

Comment: No, I'm saying that your third row operation was performed incorrectly. The third row operation should have changed the (1,3) entry again.

Comment: Yeah.. like I said in the responses to the answer below, "I went ahead and wrote out my stupidity explicitly. I guess that's why you don't get on stack exchange before writing it out on paper. Sorry for wasting everyone's time."  And thanks again

Comment: We’ve all made plenty of mistakes. Just keep on trucking! 

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\left[ \begin{array}{ccc|ccc} 1 & a & b & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & c  & 0 & 1 & 0\\ 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1\end{array} \right]$$

I believe there is a typo in your working, I believe you mean subtract $c$ times the third row and add it to the **second** row

$$\left[ \begin{array}{ccc|ccc} 1 & a & b & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 0  & 0 & 1 & -c\\ 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1\end{array} \right]$$

After which,

$$\left[ \begin{array}{ccc|ccc} 1 & a & 0 & 1 & 0 & -b \\ 0 & 1 & 0  & 0 & 1 & -c\\ 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1\end{array} \right]$$

and for the last step:

$$\left[ \begin{array}{ccc|ccc} 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & -a & ac-b \\ 0 & 1 & 0  & 0 & 1 & -c\\ 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1\end{array} \right]$$

Edit:

Your mistake is at the last step

subtract $a$ times the new second row from the first,

It should involve $(-a)(-c)+(-b)$

Comment: The typo I made was the one Ian suggested.  I corrected it.  The order of your elementary row operations gives the inverse.  I was already aware of this order.  This doesn't address my issue.  (I suppose it does help to elaborate it though.)  Can you please tell me why the 2 different orders (yours and mine) of elementary row operations gives different results for the inverse?

Comment: They don't, unless it's because of an error.

Comment: @GTonyJacobs Can you please tell me what error I made?

Comment: When you subtract $a$ times the new second row from the first, you missed that there's a $-c$ in that second row. That should add an $ac$ term to your upper-right entry.

Comment: Also, these aren't two different orders of elementary row operations. You both did the same operations, in the same order.

Comment: It seems that your first two operations involved the first row and third row, are you sure?

Comment: Your mistake is at the very last step, focus on the last column. As you multiply $-a$ to the second row, you should get $ac$ after which you should add it to $-b$ in the first row.

Comment: Yeah... I went ahead and wrote out my stupidity explicitly.  I guess that's why you don't get on stack exchange before writing it out on paper.  Sorry for wasting everyone's time